# Replacing values based on condition in Power Query

Tags: mysql, excel, powerbi, powerquery

I want to replace some acquaintance values by keywords to specific value, converting both "google" and "searching google" to "seo"

I tried replace but you should specify all the values to replace with and that's not possible.
if there is a solution with "contain" function i think it would help but i couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Custom1 = Table.TransformColumns( Source, {{"Column1",(x)=> if Text.Contains(x, "google") then "seo" else x}})
in
    Custom1
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution I used your answer and it was really helpful

`= Table.ReplaceValue(source, each[column1], each if Text.Contains(Text.From([column1]),"google") then "seo" else Text.From([column1]),Replacer.ReplaceValue,
{"column1"})`

Comment: This is great. Replacer.ReplaceValue and Replacer.ReplaceText are the building functions. But you can also write your own custom comparer function if you have specific needs. 

https://powerquery.how/Table.ReplaceValue/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a conditional column as explained here in this tutorial- [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoUpf49jGjI)

This is basically a simple new conditional column with if/else condition as shown in this below image-

[image]